# Add a PowerShell script to Azure Marketplace Offer

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-marketplace

I would like to publish an Azure Managed Application to the Azure Marketplace. Is it possible to add to the "app.zip" an own PowerShell Script, which executes some additional deployment steps besides the Azure Resource Manager Template?

The Script would invoke the arm template and handle some outputs of the Template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and contacting the MS Support I found two possible solutions:

1. Using a VM with a Custom Script Extension. Downside: VM needs long to startup and is expensive if we do not delete it afterwards.
2. Using a Azure Container Instance to run the script. Starts up in about 45 seconds and doesn't cost anything if we don't use it. -> [Tutorial](https://samcogan.com/run-scripts-in-arm-deployments-with-aci/)

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about these is that you can only do tasks that can be done in a template.  Today, there's no way to run an arbitrary script in an ARM template.

That help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there really no other way then ARM? How should I create and fill a table storage without PowerShell?

Comment: The short answer is " you can't in the marketplace" - the longer answer is that you might be able to leverage other compute you have in the solution to run that script for you.  That help?

Comment: after a bit research it seems to be more complicated as thought. Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: If your marketplace offer spins up a VM for it's workload, you can run a script on that VM via the Custom Script Extension and you can run it multiple times (not simple but possible).  But if you don't have a VM in the workload, then this isn't an option - you can spin up a VM just for this purpose because it can't be torn down when it's finished.  That help?